# Messed up cover letter used wrong company name

Tags: cover-letter

I was using a template cover letter for multiple companies and forgot to change the name of the company.

Is there any chance I still get a callback? Any way to rectify the situation?

Comment: Nobody here can tell you what HR at an arbitrary company will do. Let's just hope you didn't have "attention to detail" as one of your skills...

Comment: I've done this before - and didn't realise until several months after I was given the job and happened to be re-reading my cover letter. In that case I think nobody at the company particularly cared about cover letters. Who knows what HR at your prospective company will be like.

Answer (score 1):

> Any chance I still get a callback?

It's possible, there's no way of knowing.

> Any way to rectify situation?

Either wait and see what happens or resend it with the correct company. You don't have anything to lose.